# How to read from terminal in lazarus on ubuntu

Tags: terminal, lazarus

Lazarus can run bash scripts and commands. How to get the output of an executed command as string and later use it, for example print it with `ShowMessage`? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summary:

1. use the [tprocess](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Executing_External_Programs) class from unit process, that allows to trap console output using pipes.
2. for straightforward cases use the [Runcommand](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Executing_External_Programs#.28Process..29RunCommand) helper functions (also in process, wrap tprocess for simple cases)

Be aware that while you see console output as one stream, in fact there might be two (stdout and stderr)